# R xts quantmod получение доступа к данным по конкретному времени

Tags: r

Добрый день!
Разбираюсь с R, с работой пакетов xts и quantmod. Есть такие данные:

```
> str(h2)
‘zoo’ series from 2016-06-15 11:00:00 to 2016-09-15 14:00:00
  Data: num [1:928, 1:5] 67842 67486 67603 67465 67457 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : NULL
  ..$ : chr [1:5] "X.OPEN." "X.HIGH." "X.LOW." "X.CLOSE." ...
  Index:  POSIXct[1:928], format: "2016-06-15 11:00:00" "2016-06-15 12:00:00" "2016-06-15 13:00:00" ...
> first(h2, '1 day')
                    X.OPEN. X.HIGH. X.LOW. X.CLOSE. X.VOL.
2016-06-15 11:00:00   67842   67842  67122    67488 262740
2016-06-15 12:00:00   67486   67610  67420    67603 288875
2016-06-15 13:00:00   67603   67608  67381    67466 323498
2016-06-15 14:00:00   67465   67484  67356    67455 168991
2016-06-15 15:00:00   67457   67460  67289    67361 174965
2016-06-15 16:00:00   67363   67381  67202    67317 195579
2016-06-15 17:00:00   67320   67465  67288    67397 230255
2016-06-15 18:00:00   67397   67436  67084    67099 469379
2016-06-15 19:00:00   67096   67198  66900    67058 264430
2016-06-15 20:00:00   67040   67094  66944    67092 110503
2016-06-15 21:00:00   67092   67158  66877    66992  83041
2016-06-15 22:00:00   66993   67110  66680    66909 386905
2016-06-15 23:00:00   66909   67269  66884    67126 143373
```

Не могу разобраться как решить, к примеру, такую задачу - сравнить, соответствует ли знак разности X.CLOSE-X.OPEN в 11:00 разности X.CLOSE(13:00)-X.OPEN(12:00) по всем дням, входящим в выборку.
Для этого, первое, что не понимаю - как получить доступ к данным по времени. Т.е., к примеру, данным X.OPEN 12:00 нужного мне дня. И второе - такую задачу решал в Excel перебором всего объема данных, но ведь R векторный и в нем должно быть более удобное, быстрое и элегантное средство для такого анализа.
Заранее большое спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

Решение навскидку: преобразуем `xts` объект в `data.frame`, группируем по датам и рассчитываем нужные показатели.

```
# Загружаем пакеты
library(xts)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(lubridate)

# Генерируем данные
x <- structure(
    list(
        datetime = c("2016-06-15 11:00:00", "2016-06-15 12:00:00", "2016-06-15 13:00:00", "2016-06-15 14:00:00", "2016-06-15 15:00:00", "2016-06-15 16:00:00", "2016-06-15 17:00:00", "2016-06-15 18:00:00", "2016-06-15 19:00:00", "2016-06-15 20:00:00", "2016-06-15 21:00:00", "2016-06-15 22:00:00", "2016-06-15 23:00:00"),
        X.OPEN. = c(67842L, 67486L, 67603L, 67465L, 67457L, 67363L, 67320L, 67397L, 67096L, 67040L, 67092L, 66993L, 66909L),
        X.HIGH. = c(67842L, 67610L, 67608L, 67484L, 67460L, 67381L, 67465L, 67436L, 67198L, 67094L, 67158L, 67110L, 67269L),
        X.LOW. = c(67122L, 67420L, 67381L, 67356L, 67289L, 67202L, 67288L, 67084L, 66900L, 66944L, 66877L, 66680L, 66884L), 
        X.CLOSE. = c(67488L, 67603L, 67466L, 67455L, 67361L, 67317L, 67397L, 67099L, 67058L, 67092L, 66992L, 66909L, 67126L),
        X.VOL. = c(262740L, 288875L, 323498L, 168991L, 174965L, 195579L, 230255L, 469379L, 264430L, 110503L, 83041L, 386905L, 143373L)
    ),
    .Names = c("datetime", "X.OPEN.", "X.HIGH.", "X.LOW.", "X.CLOSE.", "X.VOL."),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -13L))
x$datetime <- as.POSIXct(x$datetime)

# Преобразуем данные в объект xts
x2 <- xts(x[, -1L], order.by = x[, 1L])


x2 %>% 
    as.data.frame() %>% 
    rownames_to_column("datetime") %>% 
    as_data_frame() %>% 
    separate(datetime, c("date", "time"), sep = " ") %>% 
    mutate(date = ymd(date)) %>% 
    mutate(time = hms(time)) %>% 
    group_by(date) %>% 
    summarise(pos_1100 = X.CLOSE.[time == hm("11:00")] - X.OPEN.[time == hm("11:00")] > 0,
              pos_1300 = X.CLOSE.[time == hm("13:00")] - X.OPEN.[time == hm("12:00")] > 0,
              res = pos_1100 == pos_1300)
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложение, Артем!